# Legality of copyright material from Z Library

Tags: copyright

I've read in multiple places that distributing copyright material that you do not own is illegal. Therefore, uploading to [Z library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Library) is considered illegal.

However, on the point of downloading material without the intent of distributing, I have seen multiple view points. Some people stating that because the user who downloaded it does not re-distribute it there is no illegal activity or at least it is a gray area, as Z library operates under principle of "information wants to be free". While others stating it is all completely illegal.

The two scenarios I'm aiming to clear up, in terms of legality, are:

1. An individual downloads from Z library an eBook that he does not own the copyright to and uses it for personal purposes and does not redistribute or sell it.
2. An individual downloads from Z library an eBook that he does not own the copyright to and uses it for commercial purposes within a company, but does not distribute it outside of the company.

Are these plain illegal? Are you able to download and use these books if you do not upload them elsewhere?

Comment: More importantly, what country are you asking about? Different countries have different laws.

Comment: "Information wants to be free" is a political slogan, not a legal principal. It is not currently, law; the whole point is to protest existing law and promote the creation of new law eliminating or relaxing copyright restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

Copyright reserves to the copyright owner the exclusive right to reproduce the work ([*Copyright Act*, s. 3](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-42/page-2.html#h-102726); [17 U.S. Code § 106](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/106)). Downloading a copyrighted work is a reproduction of that work and would be an infringement unless excepted (e.g. you have been given a licence, your download is fair dealing or fair use, etc.).

[Canada lists downloading as an example of infringment](https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/office-consumer-affairs/en/connected-consumer/notices-canadian-internet-subscribers).

And the [United States says](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-digital.html):

> Uploading or downloading works protected by copyright without the authority of the copyright owner is an infringement of the copyright owner's exclusive rights of reproduction and/or distribution

You say: "uploading to Z library is considered illegal." This implies the content on Z library is generally protected by copyright and not licenced for distribution via Z library, but that is a factual question.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of light can be shed on the topic by looking at [German copyright law](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html), as well as aspects of US law. Insofar as the question relates to reconciling contradictory viewpoints on the legality of downloading infringed works purely for personal use and there does exist a mistaken popular belief that copyright law only protects against for-profit redistribution, it is not pointless to wonder where such an idea might have come from.

§53 of the German copyright statute says

> (1) It is permitted for a natural person to make single copies of a
> work for private use on any medium, insofar as they neither directly
> nor indirectly serve commercial purposes, as long as no obviously
> unlawfully produced model or a model which has been unlawfully made
> available to the public is used for the copying. A person authorised
> to make copies may also have another person make such copies if no
> payment is received therefor, or if it involves copies on paper or a
> similar medium which have been effected by the use of any kind of
> photomechanical technique or by some other process having a similar
> effect.

The law is [written in German](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/), and I cannot speak to the reasonableness of the translation. This appears to allow personal-use non-commercial downloading, the only limitation being that you cannot use an "obviously unlawfully produced model or a model which has been unlawfully made available to the public". Jen's answer correctly points out (to rephrase the conclusion) that only the copyright owner knows whether a given work available on such a website is made available with permission (I am certain about the infringing character of one book there). It is *not* a reasonable conclusion that any book on that site is "obviously illegally uploaded", therefore it is arguable under German copyright law that non-commercial downloading of pirated material is legal.

US ["fair use"](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/fair-use/info) also provides a reason for thinking that redistribution and for-profit are what copyright law protects against: criterion 1 opposes commercial use vs. nonprofit educational use, and criterion 4 sanctions copying based on impact on the market for or the value of a work.

This does not mean that personal-use downloading *is* legal, it means that the belief that it is legal has some seeds in actual law.

Answer (score -1):

Others have covered the general case.

Here is a corner case, which applies to many types of records, which are *technically* in the public domain but are nonetheless paywalled.   It is surprising, but there is a war going on relating to this content - a real one with a body count.

Long before the Internet age, when photocopies first emerged and were costly, these custodians offered a photocopy service and charged fees owing simply to the cost of early xerography.  As copying got cheaper, *they did not lower their feees* and it became a profit center for the custodian.  In the Internet age, it makes no sense (most documents are digital anyway) -- but the practice has continued because the custodians are now addicted to the revenue stream. The logic was "it funds the archive" but the archive was turning into an ever larger bureaucracy, and often was even looted by the parent agency, who was unprepared to see that profit center turn into an expense center.

For instance this applies to the Federal PACER court document system, but it echoed in most state and county courts, where "$1 per page" fees are not uncommon.

In those cases, it is perfectly legitimate for individuals *who have paid* for the privilege of accessing those documents to share them into a public archive.  Indeed, the most prominent is [the RECAP system](https://free.law/recap/), which is a browser add-on which (in the background) grabs copies every PDF document you buy from PACER. It also stops you from paying for documents RECAP already has copied.

Fortunately, this being a government actor in the legal space, PACER recognized the weakness of their position, and abstained from SLAPP or copyright-troll behavior against copiers.  Nonetheless, they loudly discouraged use of RECAP, and that snowballed into wide scrutiny of their excess profits, and legal action which still continues.

A similar thing happened with JSTOR, which is an archive of a mix of public-domain scholarly journals, as well as copyrighted journals.  An information-freedom activist, Aaron Swartz, [used a university guest account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSTOR#Aaron_Swartz_incident) to download a large part of the JSTOR archive. There's no question Swartz aimed to release *at least the public-domain material* to a public archive, it's not known if Swartz intended to cull the copyrighted content before doing so.  Nonetheless, Swartz was charged with a litany of Federal data-theft charges, dropped after Swartz' untimely death. JSTOR coldly said it "had been working on making this material free for some time"... and "We do not believe that just because something is in the public domain, it can always be provided for free".

A more murky case is when private organizations craft *[model laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_act)* with the hopes each State will adopt that as their law. This provides consistency of law, broadening markets; and spares the States the cost of a vast bureaucracy of specialists expert in those fields to write the laws.  At its simplest, look at UPMIFA's reform of endowment law - a few pages long, eagerly  distributed for free, on hopes of universal adoption. States copy-pasted the language straight into their law books. A great way to do a model law.

But other creators of more complex model laws found themselves (pre-Internet) with a huge revenue center selling paper copies to the trade. They protected that revenue by having states "[incorporate their model law by reference](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/incorporate_by_reference)" rather than copy-pasting the full text into state law books. Thus, any interested party had to pay coin to the private organization *to even see* the law which bound them.  This created an awkward situation of "secret laws" with "gate guardians" and conflicting with the concepts of freedom of information.  It could be argued that the State is **licensing** that model law for the free use of all its citizens, the citizens can't be denied access to it, and if the organization failed to make a good licensing deal, that's their problem.

The case law is poor here, because the organizations are maneuvering to keep it out of litigation. For instance NFPA provides a "walled garden" access to the National* Electrical Code for free, albeit behind a signup-wall (necessitating agreement to terms and conditions). This deflates most people's desire to have the law daylighted.

The upshot is that in some cases, massive theft of material to place in a public archive may be *entirely legal*, since the material is already public domain and thus not capable of being stolen.

---

* For countries in North America which are not Canada, and some in South America.

Comment: Paywalling and copyright are two separate things. You can paywall something in the public domain, since there is no copyright on it. And you can paywall something that is copyrighted, as long as you have permission to distribute it in that manner. Indeed, even open source software (GPL) can be paywalled, as long as you do so in a manner compatible with the licensing terms. Basically for the GPL, it means that if you charge a fee for (i.e. "to paywall") a binary version of a program, then you must also offer the source code version to the same person at no additional charge.

Comment: @Brandin interesting facts, yes. I don't mean to suggest it's illegal to paywall public domain material. I'm saying if someone does, there are no consequences for copying and uploading it.  I admit I'm a bit off-topic since OP specified copyright material, but there is often confusion there.